# Не загружается ресурсы spring application сервере томкат удаленном хосте

Tags: java, spring, сервер, tomcat

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Я установил томкат на удаленный сервер , когда делаю деплой своего проекта написанный спринге , проект запускается , однако почему - то не загружается ресурсы , если перезагрузить страницу - то все норм , но без перезагрузки с первого раза не загружает ресурсы. Ошибка "Failed to load resouce jquery-2.2.1.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Чуть неправильно написал - не со второго после, а после нескольких раз перезагрузки страницы ресурсы правильно загружается даже после <kbd>ctrl</kbd>`+`<kbd>f5</kbd> все норм.

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED только такую ошибку выдаёт указанием название файла jquery-2.2.1.min.js:1 без кода ошибки

Comment: Проверьте в каком месте страницы вы их подгружаете. Судя по описанному поведению, они загружаются у вас позже, чем идет обращение к ним

Comment: Здравствуйте, я загружаю их в конце страницы , локально все работает только на сервере такая проблема .

Comment: подгрузите их в head. В конце страницы надо подгружать скрипты в которых вы ссылаетесь на элементы DOM - тогда важно, чтоб все элементы DOM были загружены, чтоб избежать ошибок.

Comment: подгрузил не помогло может дело в томкате у меня одном томкате 3 проекта развернуто.

Comment: На мой взгляд tomcat здесь вообще не причем. Если вы пишите что после повторного обновления у вас все работает, то файл на клиента грузится, со второго раза он работает потому что закэшировался после первой загрузки - если вы нажмете например ctrl+f5 - скорей всего опять будет ошибка. Отсюда я сделал вывод, что дело в последовательности загрузки страницы. Или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код страницы, которая у вас не загружается.